# Reset the zoom on the viewport meta tag when using Frames

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a fairly 'mature' site that has an html frameset set up. The viewport meta tag is set on the outer frames (it doesn't seem to work if used on the inner ones) like this.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Window-target" content="_top" />
    <base target="_top" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=3, user-scalable=1">
</head>
<frameset  cols="*,0">
    <frame>...</frame>
</frameset>
</html>
```

If I then zoom in on a page and proceed to the next one, the zoom stays in place when I really want it to reset to the default.

I've tried resetting the meta tag using javascript but as that hasn't actually changed, it doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated.